# Format decimal day as 24-hour HH:MM:SS

Tags: mariadb

How, **w/o rounding up**, do I get 'Decimal Day' into HH:MM:SS format using SQL?

Using MariaDB 5.x, one of the DB fields contains a pseudo date-time, as day.time.

| DB 'Time' col | Day | Decimal 24-hour time | HH:MM:SS Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1234567890 | 0 | .1234567890 | 02:57:46 |
| 1.4567890123 | 1 | .4567890123 | 10:57:46 |
| 2.8901234567 | 2 | .8901234567 | 21:21:46 |

I'm able to pull the day out from the TIME column using:  `SELECT dbTime - MOD(dbTime, 1) AS 'Day'`

And I can separate the decimal time using:  `MOD(dbTime, 1) AS 'Decimal Day'`

I can't figure out how to get 'Decimal Day' into HH:MM:SS format? I have played around with two different numbers using the following SQL, which gives me the individual HH:MM:SS numbers, but the numbers always round up whenever I try using `format`, `cast`, or `convert`.

| Decimal Day | HH:MM:SS Time |
| --- | --- |
| .51923075705577 | 12:27:41 |
| .52923075705577 | 12:42:05 |

```
SELECT .51923075705577 * 24 AS 'hour', 
       mod((.51923075705577 * 24), 1) * 60 AS 'minute', 
       mod((mod((.51923075705577 * 24), 1) * 60), 1) * 60 AS 'seconds';
```

The times shown above are the desired result.

Thanks for any assistance on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(86400 * .51923075705577);
+--------------------------------------+
| SEC_TO_TIME(86400 * .51923075705577) |
+--------------------------------------+
| 12:27:41.537410                      |
+--------------------------------------+
```

(There are 86400 seconds in a day.)

```
mysql> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(86400 * 0.999999);
+-------------------------------+
| SEC_TO_TIME(86400 * 0.999999) |
+-------------------------------+
| 23:59:59.913600               |
+-------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(86400 * 0.001);
+----------------------------+
| SEC_TO_TIME(86400 * 0.001) |
+----------------------------+
| 00:01:26.400               |
+----------------------------+
```

To avoid fractional seconds:

```
+---------------------------------------------+
| SEC_TO_TIME(ROUND(86400 * .51923075705577)) |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 12:27:42                                    |
+---------------------------------------------+
+---------------------------------------------+
| SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(86400 * .51923075705577)) |
+---------------------------------------------+
| 12:27:41                                    |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems fairly easy to do this using the built-in MySQL function, `DATE_ADD` combined with a `CONVERT(..., TIME)` statement.

So, for the last decimal number in your question:

```
SET @seconds = 0.52923075705577 * 86400;
SELECT DATE_ADD(CONVERT(0, TIME), INTERVAL @seconds SECOND) AS Result;
```

Results:

| Result |
| --- |
| 12:42:05.537409 |

The `86400` is a constant representing the number of seconds in a day, and will work for days where there is no leap second.  Leap seconds are extremely rare, so ignoring this slight inconsistency should not be problematic for most situations.

Docs for the MySQL date and time functions are [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Yes, thank you, this works too. I used the following to get the HH:MM:SS format:  `TIME_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(CONVERT(0,TIME), INTERVAL (MOD(a.Time, 1) * 86400) SECOND), '%H:%i:%s') as 'Result'`